# Why a domain controler cannot run VMware Server?

Tags: domain-controller, vmware-server

When I try to install VMWare server on a domain controller the installer says that it's not recommended? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/11608/any-issues-with-running-vmware-server-on-an-active-directory-server).

Answer (score 1):

DCs have the disk write cache disabled. This will probably cause quite a bit of performance degradation to any hosted VMs. I would really recommend against it.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason is that if it dies or the VM chokes, your in quite a bit of trouble.

Comment: This reasom means that no critical service can be ran on a VM.

Comment: Essentially, it implies that critical services should be one to a machine, and you should have a dedicated VM host to run your VMs on. This is why things like hyper-v and vmware ESX are so popular.